# Where exactly do DApps run? Who gets rewarded for running them?

Tags: mining, dapps, evm, contract-invocation

So I am currently running a full node, as well as a GPU miner. I am curious first of all where do DApps get run? They wouldn't make sense to run on a GPU as they aren't very parallizable, so I am assuming by a full node. But I never noticed any income being generated by my full node. Where does all the Ether go that is used in Gas to run a DApp? Someone must be running them, and I presume they would get the gas a reward?

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking here. I suggest you read more about [DApps](http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/383/87), [Contracts](http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/20/87) and [Gas](http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/3/87) first.

Comment: I am asking who executes the source code of a DApp, is it someone running a full node, or a miner? Also when I run my DApps (and yes I have written several) I have to pay gas, to whom does that Ether go.

Comment: @5chdn That was directed at you ^^^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Decentralized apps](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/383/87) can be hosted on webspaces or on github or on local machines and nobody really gets rewarded for them. I think you are mistaking the term with smart contracts.

[Contracts](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/20/87) are [executed in the ethereum virtual machine](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/357/87) and validated by the miners who include the contract-deploying transactions. The [gas](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/3/87) spent to deploy the contract and the [gas costs](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/52/87) of interacting with contracts are converted to fees and paid to the miners. Just like the transaction fees in Bitcoin are rewarded to the miners.

The fees calculate from the [gas price](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/324/87) * gas amount. Current gas price is around 50,000,000,000 wei, and the minimum gas amount to for a transaction is 21,000 gas, resulting in a minimum fee of around 1,050,000,000,000,000 wei (0.00105 ETH).

Comment: Thank you, yes I did indeed mean Smart Contracts it seems. The only detail that confuses me is that I've been mining for a few days now. I mine blocks all the time, but that seems to have a fixed payout of 5ETH or so (much higher than gas prices). So why isnt my miner earning showing that it is earning gas at any point? Is there some special setup I have to do to ensure the miner earns gas and not just blocks? Once they move to PoS does this mean it will still require miners to be setup on the network to support it?