# Diffrent between smart contract and dapp

Tags: dapps

I struggle with the following questions about definitions.

Is a dapp just the implementation of a smart contract? So when someone says he is writing a smart contract he is actually writing a dapp?

Also, can I write a dapp which is not a smart contract or is any dapp automaticly a smart contract?

Thanks for helping me out.

Comment: Slightly related: [What is the difference between a smart contract and a DAO?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/3336/what-is-the-difference-between-a-smart-contract-and-a-dao)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple short answer:

What backend is to a web app, smart contract is to Decentralized app(Dapp).

Answer (score 0):

Smart contract includes the decentralized and trustless logic of the application run on Ethereum virtual machine by all Ethereum nodes.

dApp generally includes web user interface (HTML) for this that interacts with the user wallet (MetaMask) that then interactws with Ethereum nodes.